# Until statement not working on simple code

Tags: ruby, loops

I'm trying to set up a pretty simple dice roll and response in the prompt and it's not working right. I wanted the loop to keep asking until the user inputs roll, Roll or ROLL.

```
def roll()
  x = rand(5) + 1
  y = rand(5) + 1
  z = rand(5) + 1
  puts "You rolled #{x},#{y},#{z}"
  if x == y && y == z
    puts "TRIPS! Trip #{x}s"
  elsif x == y || y == z || x == z
    puts "Pair!"
  else
    if x > y && x > z
      puts "#{x} high"
    end
    if y > x && y > z
      puts "#{z} high"
    end
    if z > x && z > y
      puts "#{z} high"
    end
  end
end

puts "Type 'roll' when you're ready."
entry = gets.chomp

until entry == roll || Roll || ROLL
  puts "Type 'roll' when you're ready."
  entry = gets.chomp
end

roll()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can do it in a more Ruby fashion that makes it more extensible.

Start with making your `roll` method focused on one very simple thing:

```
def roll(sides = 6, count = 3)
  Array.new(count) { rand(sides) + 1 }
end
```

Note that `rand(5)` produces values in the range of `0..4`, it never yields `5`. The idea here is to return an array that's of arbitrary length, and by having exposed arguments with defaults you can re-purpose this method easily for other situations.

Then move all of the display logic to the main loop:

```
loop do
  puts "Type 'roll' when you're ready."
  entry = gets.chomp

  case (entry.downcase)
  when 'roll'
    rolls = roll

    puts "You rolled #{rolls.join(', ')}"

    case (rolls.uniq.length)
    when 1
      puts "TRIPS! Trip #{rolls[0]}s"
    when 2
      puts "Pair!"
    else
      puts "#{rolls.max} high"
    end

    break
  when 'quit'
    break
  end
end
```

Using an array structure instead of three arbitrary variables helps considerably when working with them in aggregate. You can see how things like `uniq` and `max` are effortless in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Remove these two lines and just use them in the while / until
# puts "Type 'roll' when you're ready"
# entry = gets.chomp


entry = ''
# Use String.downcase on entry because the user could type rOLL or RoLl
while entry.downcase != 'roll' # or you can use until entry.downcase == 'roll'
  puts "Type 'roll' when you're ready."
  entry = gets.chomp
end
```

You are comparing entry to values that do not exist. You need to compare to a string.

**Roll** by convention should be a class / model / object of some kind. For example

```
class Roll
   # create roll
   def initialize()
   end
end
roll = Roll.new
# or for an existing class like Arrays
array = Array.new
```

**ROLL** by convention would be a previously defined constant.

```
ROLL = 7
# => 7
ROLL = 4
# => warning: already initialized constant ROLL
```