# Breaking a loop when a user types a certain input

Tags: ruby, loops

So I'm trying to break a loop when a user type `done` and from there jump into another method called "survey" that asks a few leftover questions.

This is what I have a the moment:

```
def survey
    puts "For how many years have you had these allergies?"
    name = gets.chomp.to_i

    puts "When was your last allergy reaction?"
    reaction = gets.chomp.to_i
end

def allergies

    puts "Please enter all your allergies. When you are finished, type 'done'."
    allergy = gets.chomp.downcase!

    while allergy != "done"

        # Format the loop so that when the user types 'done'
        # The loop breaks and we go to the 'survey' method

        allergy = gets.chomp.downcase
        survey
        if allergy == "nuts"
            puts "Beware! The food item contains peanuts!"
            break
        end
    end
end

allergies
```

At the moment it just lets me type in one allergy and thenk skips right into the survey method. How can I change this so I can keep inputting allergies until I either type "nuts" or "done"?

Comment: This is answered exactly here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42403470/6163262

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def survey
    puts "For how many years have you had these allergies?"
    name = gets.chomp.to_i

    puts "When was your last allergy reaction?"
    reaction = gets.chomp.to_i
end

def allergies

    puts "Please enter all your allergies. When you are finished, type 'done'."
    allergy = gets.chomp.downcase!

    while allergy != "done"

        # Format the loop so that when the user types 'done'
        # The loop breaks and we go to the 'survey' method

        allergy = gets.chomp.downcase
        if allergy == "nuts"
            puts "Beware! The food item contains peanuts!"
            break
        elsif allergy == "done"
          survey
        end
    end
end

allergies
```

Answer (score 1):

Try an `if-else` statement

```
def allergies

    puts "Please enter all your allergies. When you are finished, type 'done'."
    allergy = gets.chomp.downcase!

    while allergy != "done"
        if allergy == "nuts"
            puts "Beware! The food item contains peanuts!"
            break
        else
            survey
        end

        allergy = gets.chomp.downcase
    end
end
```